# how to fix file upload with ant design react typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, antd

I have form with ant design that contains a file and two string fields, although I followed the documentation to upload the file , the upload did not work correctly.
this is a code snippet from the form:

```
  <Form.Item
              name="resume"
              label="Resume"
              rules={[
                { required: true, message: "Please upload your resume!" },
              ]}
            >
              <Upload name='resume' {...props}>
                <Button icon={<UploadOutlined />}>Select Resume</Button>
              </Upload>
            </Form.Item>
```

when I upload the Resume here's the output:
[image]

I tried to use drag and drop and the same error occurs.